# How to install embedly-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedly

I am new to programming and trying to install embedly-ruby into my social bookmarking application to display a list of bookmark previews.  I have read and watched everything I could find on embedly and embedly-ruby and need some clarification about the installation process.  This is what I understand from my research.  Please correct me if I'm wrong:

Step 1:  add `gem 'embedly'` to Gemfile

Step 2:  Run bundle in terminal....or do I just do `gem install embedly`in terminal without adding `gem 'embedly'` to my Gemfile?

Step 3:  Add the require lines to the application.js file like this (should I worry about order here?)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require 'embedly'
//= require 'json'
```

I'm not sure how to proceed after this.  So here are my questions:

Question 1:  What is this code for?  Where does it go?

```
embedly_api =
Embedly::API.new :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
```

Question 2:  Where do I put this code?

```
# single url
obj = embedly_api.oembed :url => “http://#{bookmark.url}”
puts obj[0].marshal_dump
json_obj = JSON.pretty_generate(obj[0].marshal_dump)
puts json_obj
```

Question 3:  Since I am trying to pull several user bookmarks from the database and display them on the site with embedly, would this line from the above code theoretically work?

```
obj = embedly_api.oembed :url => “http://#{bookmark.url}”
```

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Comment: FYI -- it looks like these examples are coming from the gem docs: https://github.com/embedly/embedly-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caveat -- I haven't personally used the gem you're using. The following suggestions are based on poking around their docs.

1. Add `embedly` to your Gemfile
2. Do **not** add it in the command line. Adding it to the Gemfile installs it within the scope of your app. (The gem instructions are framework-agnostic, which is why they don't show it in a Gemfile).
3. I'm not sure this gem includes a JS file you need to require. Assuming that installing that gem somehow **does** add a JS file, that require looks OK to me (although I forget if it's a problem that your last two requires are strings, and in my experience, it's conventional to put the `require_tree .` last, so that your app-specific JS files have access to all the libraries). If anything, it's probably only important that it follows the `jquery` line, as Embedly's JS **might** depend on some jQuery, which is a very common library.

The following line generates an **instance** of the `Embedly::API` class given by the gem:

```
embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
```

That instance has an `oembed` method that can be fed a hash with a `:url` key, the value of which it can use to generate HTML that you can print to your page. So, for instance, after having defined the above `embedly_api` instance, you could use it like so:

```
embedly_api.oembed(url: "someurl.com")
```

or

```
embedly_api.oembed(url: ["someurl.com", "anotherurl.com"])
```

The docs suggest you can set `url` to equal a string or array of strings.

This method returns an array of url-based objects, each with a handful of relevant methods, including `html`, which seems to print out the HTML for an iFrame, and `thumbnail`, which seems to print out a thumbnail image for the link.

You can try this out in the Rails console:

```
[1] ruby> embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
=> #<Embedly::API:0x00000102282e88
 @api_version={:objectify=>"2"},
 @endpoints=[:oembed, :objectify, :preview, :extract],
 @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)"},
 @hostname="http://api.embed.ly",
 @key=nil,
 @proxy=nil,
 @secret=nil,
 @timeout=180>
[2] ruby> embedly_api.oembed :url => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPbJ4Z5D-n4&feature=topvideos'
=> [#<Embedly::EmbedlyObject provider_url="http://www.youtube.com/", description="Netherlands - Austria [09-02-2011] 1-0 WESLEY SNEIJDER", title="Netherlands - Austria [09-02-2011] 1-0 WESLEY SNEIJDER", url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPbJ4Z5D-n4", author_name="TranceAddict1989", height=480, thumbnail_width=480, width=854, html="<iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DsPbJ4Z5D-n4&src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FsPbJ4Z5D-n4%3Ffeature%3Doembed&image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FsPbJ4Z5D-n4%2Fhqdefault.jpg&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=youtube\" width=\"854\" height=\"480\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", author_url="http://www.youtube.com/user/TranceAddict1989", version="1.0", provider_name="YouTube", thumbnail_url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/sPbJ4Z5D-n4/hqdefault.jpg", type="video", thumbnail_height=360>]
```

You could then try using this **in your app** by defining `embedly_api` in a controller, and use it to generate an array of url-relevant iFrame/thumbnail HTML strings from your Bookmarks. Set that array as an `@` variable and loop through those iFrame/thumbnail strings and print them to the page as HTML.

Once you've done that, you should have a better sense of what exactly the gem is doing for you, and how you might want to customize its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Using the embedly-ruby library will still require a lot of display work on your part. You may want to consider trying a client side library like http://embed.ly/cards, which is completely free.